# Which ready-made programs can I use for running a preference-rating experiment?

Tags: social-psychology, measurement, methodology, experimental-psychology, software

I'd like to run an experiment in which 64 images are presented (1 at a time) and participants rate their preference for the image on a slider scale, and I'm wondering what the best and cheapest way to do this is? Are there some good, free software programs that I can use? I've looked at things like SurveyMonkey and Question Pro but have not found something that seems to work. I don't have any coding knowledge so I'd prefer not to build it from scratch.

Comment: it sounds like a simple webpage with asp.net maybe 5-10 hours of work at $15 a hour for a undergrad cs major.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using [TRUE](http://www.salleurl.edu/tsenyal/true/) and it seems quite fine. There is free access to
TRUE online version.